# Esp32cam Failed to connect to ESP32: Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: arduino, esp32, ftdi

I've just recieved my very first esp32cam (AI THINKER) today and I was excited to test it, *but* I'm unable to upload any code to it. I'm always getting the following error:

```
Failed to connect to ESP32: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

So, the FTDI I'm using is the FT232r with the following wiring scheme

[FTDI Wiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evu9W.png)

**How I reproduce this error:**

- Plug everything
- Order IDE to upload the sketch
- Wait for the "connecting" text
- Press the RST button

**Also:**

- Plug everything
- Press the RST button
- Order IDE to upload the sketch

**I've already tried:**

- Switching to 3.3v (plugged on 3.3v pin)
- Using external 5v power supply (plugged on 5v pin)
- Using another computer
- Swapping RX TX
- Trying in different upload speeds
- Holding RST button
- Switching board between ESP32 Wrover Module and AI Thinker ESP32

I'm I doing something wrong or there's just something faulty?

Comment: Have you test it with an example from the available sketch (File > examples > esp32 > camera > CameraWebServer)

Comment: Yep, that was the first try. The second one was just a simple sketch that says "Hello world" in the serial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by using other jumpers. It seems one of the jumpers used in the wiring was faulty.

If you're having the same issue and tried everything in this post, try checking your cables!

Answer (score 4):

I have delved for a solution in this regard for weeks and it seems I have a solution.

Findings-

1. FTDI module is probably faulty or not supported for each instance.
2. Aithinker Board is not compatible with esspressif (use ESP32Wrover, more details below )

I have an esp32cam from Esspressif, not Aithinker.

I was trying with ***FT232rl*** , No matter what Voltage/jumpers/USB cable I used, it didn't work. Always stuck with fatal timed out error.

After many futile attempts with FTDI breakout, I gave my Arduino UNO a try (please note my UNO has ***mega16u2*** chip as USB serial chip (top right corner just beside the oscillator) and fortunately it worked.

I have read that ***CP2102*** is also working.

```
                        **Here are the steps to follow-**
```

1. Arduino ESP32Cam connections

   ```
   3.3 Arduino --------- 3v Esp32CAM 
   GND Arduino ------------ GND Esp32CAM
   RESET Arduino to Ardunio GND
   RX Arduino -------------- VOR Esp32CAM (this is not a mistake RX to rx & TX to tx)
   TX Arduino -------------- VOT Esp32CAM
   GPIO 0(zero)(written as IO0) Esp32CAM to GND Esp32CAM
   ```
2. I didn't have any need to press the reset button in any part of the operation before & during uploading.
3. I am assuming You have pre-installed the esp32 board manager.

- Now select the correct COM port where your Uno (in this case) is
  plugged in.
- Select the correct board as mentioned

  ```
    Tools>Board>ESP32 Arduino > select ESP32 Wrover Module
  ```
- Some uploading setups are to be Done (Under Tools, these will only appear when the Wrover module is selected )

  ```
   Upload speed -- 115200
   Flash Frequency -- 40Mhz
   Flash Mode -- QIO
   Partition Scheme --- Huge App
   Port ---- select the right com port for your breakout or UNO
  ```

JUST press upload and relax

After a while, you will be able to see this message

```
        Leaving...
        Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

- Disconnect the Esp32Cam GPIO 0 and GND
- Power the ESP32Cam with 5/3v with external power supply (Arduino or other breakouts may not be able unless you are connected with a Powered USB Hub)
- keep TX, RX, & GND of the 2 boards connected, don't disconnect Arduino Reset and GND.
- Press Reset on ESPCAM and open Serial monitor and you will be able to see the IP address of the cam if it was configured with your wifi correctly.OR get any network scanner App on android or windows.

I hope it helped.

Comment: I thought I had tried everything but "Huge App" partition scheme was the missing piece for me, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for sharing, that is essential. Some may find it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Pre-requisites for flashing:

- ArduinoIDE 1.8.12
- Core ESP32 1.04 (at time of writing)
- Select board AI Thinker Cam
- uplooad speed 921600
- freq 240Mhz
- flashfreq 80Mhz
- mode QIO if not working try DIO
- partition scheme default
- Serial monitor is closed
- NO hardware connected to the pins of the ESPcam
- Make sure the USB cable is a data cable and NO loading cable only
- check Windows device manager if programmer is shown and has max speed / 8n1 hardware

Connections

```
    FTDI    -   ESP32
    GND         GND
     5V          5V
    TXD         UOR
    RXD         UOT
```

If you use an AIThinker Cam clone you have to ground GIPO 0:

- connect GPIO 0 with a dupont wire connected to GND
- press reset
- compile and upload (use AI THINKER CAM)
- optional:

  - press reset
  - upload filesystem data (SPIFFS)
- disconnect GPIO 0 and GND
- press reset
- code should execute

And yes you have to do it every upload, on my dev board I soldered a little switch with proper isolation
Some more solutions from experience:

- If there is still a problem use a 10K (or so) pull-down resistor between RX0 and GND (test on breadboard before soldering)
- Pressing and holding (!) the boot-button while uploading on some "bad" boards
- Happened with a "normal" ESP32 board to me - just to be sure -  I got an ESP8266 in an ESP32 packaging. Configuring for the ESP8266 solved the issue of uploading.

Comment: I'm already connecting GPIO 0 to GND. I'll follow step by step and see if I get any advance.

Comment: See my complete checklist - if nothing of these steps works asume your board DOA

Comment: Nothing worked. It's time to assume she'd dead.. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In my case I forgot to remove the SD card. Other users recommended removing unnecessary connections to the pins-- and the SD card technically uses some of those :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution here. Just to add, I tried everything on this QA, as well as many other things suggested online. e.g. tested by powering from 3.3V then 5V, various permutations of holding the reset button down and disconnecting IO00 from GND at the point of flashing. Changing various settings in Arduino IDE/

I was unable to flash a single one of the 5 ESP32-CAM boards I bought. Spent a good two hours on it. I even continuity tested every pin on the board to its ESP32 chip pad, and all the hookup wires were tested too. The board seemed fine.

Then I soldered a 100uF capacitor between 5V and GND, and used my USB-UART 5V power... tested and worked straight away. No need to pull out the IO00->GND connection and no need to press RST button on the board during flashing. (Of course, pull out IO00->GND after flashing complete.

So - it was a power problem.

I can only guess that the cheapo regulator they used on the copy of board that I got was not quite efficient enough, but basically that capacitor resolved the issue.

p.s. the ESP on board was marked "ESP32-S". I selected "AI Thinker ESP32-CAM" in Arduino IDE as suggested by most people online, and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 pins marked `GND` on the ESP32-CAM board. Buuuuut (!) the one marked `GND/R` just by the `U0T` is NOT connected to other grounds or anywhere else I could had find. Check with a multimeter and use a REAL GND. It just worked for me after days of puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your Programmer(CP2102 or FT232rl) GND to ESP32 Cam GND and connect again every time before flasing the new program. It worked or me.

Answer (score -1):

If you try it with arduino it works but its needed to press reset button on esp32 before you upload your code

Comment: If during uploading tx led on Uno doesnt shine press reset button on esp32 again
Do it every time when it snuffs out

Answer (score -2):

Basically I was facing the exact same problem fro quite some time. What worked for me was that as the chip was flashing, shifting the power wire from 5V to 3V3 pin. I do not know why but it workes. When esptool starts flashing at 2%, switching the cable just then, despite having 5V from supply into the 3V3 point made the flashing successful. I do realize this is probably a bad answer to your problem since it involves oversupplying voltage to the chip on the wrong point as it is flashing and could damage the chip. However, if anyone is tired of debugging and are at the point where you are considering throwing the chip away, might as well try my method. For other's who value their chip, don't try this method and if you still do, kniw it is at your own risk. But it worked for me after 3 days of just messing around with connections.